# Python best practice in terms of logging

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

When using the `logging` module from python for logging purposes. Is it best-practice to define a logger for each class?

Considering some things would be redundant such as file log location, I was thinking of abstracting logging to its own class and import an instance into each of my classes requiring logging. However I'm not sure if this is best practice or not?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Use JSON or YAML logging configuration** - After Python 2.7, you can load logging configuration from a dict. It means you can load the logging configuration from a JSON or YAML file.

**Yaml Example**  -

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False
formatters:
    simple:
        format: "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"

handlers:
    console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: simple
        stream: ext://sys.stdout

    info_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: INFO            
        formatter: simple
        filename: info.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 20
        encoding: utf8

    error_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: ERROR            
        formatter: simple
        filename: errors.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 20
        encoding: utf8

loggers:
    my_module:
        level: ERROR
        handlers: [console]
        propagate: no

root:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [console, info_file_handler, error_file_handler]
```

Ref -  [Good-logging-practice-in-python](https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/)

Answer (score 35):

Best practice is to follow Python's rules for software (de)composition - the module is the unit of Python software, not the class. Hence, the recommended approach is to use

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

in each module, and to configure logging (using `basicConfig()` or `dictConfig()`) from the main script.

Loggers are singletons - there is no point in passing them around or storing them in instances of your classes.

Comment: Does `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` go at the top of the module or inside each function/method that wants to log?

Comment: @industryworker3595112 at the top of the module (after the `import` statements)

Comment: While I usually instantiate my `logger` at module level as well, there are some arguments in favor of doing it within the class: https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/

Answer (score 3):

Use *structured logging*. Two great tools for this:

- [Eliot](https://eliot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/): Logging that tells you why it happened

> Most logging systems tell you what happened in your application,
>   whereas eliot also tells you why it happened.
>
> eliot is a Python logging system that outputs causal chains of
>   actions: actions can spawn other actions, and eventually they either
>   succeed or fail. The resulting logs tell you the story of what your
>   software did: what happened, and what caused it.

- [Structlog](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/): structlog makes logging in Python less painful and more powerful by adding structure to your log entries.

> Structured logging means that you don’t write hard-to-parse and
>   hard-to-keep-consistent prose in your logs but that you log events
>   that happen in a context instead.

---

I've had very positive experiences with Eliot.